# How to use objects(such as Users) in some Ruby file and execute it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

I have such problem: I need to take all Users and its associated objects perform some actions with them. This file should be executed once a month (it is for payments). I'm programming in Windows, but server could be on *nix.

Here what I want to do in code:

```
      @users = User.all
       @emails ||= Array.new
       @amounts||= Array.new
      @users.each do |user|
      emails.push(user.email)//array of emails
      amounts.push(user.websites.amount)//it will be arrray of amounts
      //then I will make post request, which I do can with static values
```

How I can use User.all ?
Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create a custom rake task for this in your Rails app. Look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks/) on how to create a task.

Comment: Thanks. It is very old railscast, could be problems with that ? Is it will be ok do it on Windows ?

Comment: If you have Ruby and your Rails app on Windows, no problem.

Comment: Ok, If I will have some troubles with realization I will return with questions.